# When to release piano sustain pedal

Tags: theory, piano

I just recently upgraded to a digital piano with sustain pedal and am trying to learn this song at the moment: https://musescore.com/carlosgbrozatti/jhin

Right of the bat it tells me to press the sustain pedal, but do I release the sustain pedal after every bar or do I keep it pressed when it tells me to press the sustain pedal again in the next bar?

If I have to release the pedal after every bar, how would I play this:

[image]

In the second bar it tells me to play two notes at the same time and keep them pressed until the third bar is over, but if I press the pedal while holding these two notes, let go of the keys and afterwards let go of the pedal at the beginning of the third bar, the two notes wont be played anymore.

Anyone mind helping me out, havent found anything useful in the search results of music.stackexchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems totally pointless releasing and grabbing again. That means holding down the l.h., which is effectively why we have the sustain pedal. In this music, I say it's not written well. Normally the pedal is released as you play the next part, which is then grabbed again before taking the hand/s off. Re-pedalling that part is like a broken pencil. Pointless.

Comment: It's possible that the point of releasing and pressing the pedal in that fashion is to reduce the volume of the held notes sharply while midway through playing them. Granted, I don't think the formatting of the original sheet music is very good--if I were a music editor for that piece, I'd suggest rewriting the pedal marking to have fewer Ped. marks.